# How to retrieve response JSON data with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, yelp

I am trying to use the Yelp API and receive the corresponding JSON according to a search term. Here is the YelpAPI Client I am using:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let yelpConsumerKey = "KLGXXXXfnmhQ"
let yelpConsumerSecret = "wPmXXXXvOA"
let yelpToken = "0-3DsXXXXhAq"
let yelpTokenSecret = "BViXXXXQ-Dz3Y"

class YelpClient: BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager {
    var accessToken: String!
    var accessSecret: String!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    class var sharedInstance : YelpClient {
        struct Static {
            static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance : YelpClient? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = YelpClient(consumerKey: yelpConsumerKey, consumerSecret: yelpConsumerSecret, accessToken: yelpToken, accessSecret: yelpTokenSecret)
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    init(consumerKey key: String!, consumerSecret secret: String!, accessToken: String!, accessSecret: String!) {
        self.accessToken = accessToken
        self.accessSecret = accessSecret
        var baseUrl = NSURL(string: "http://api.yelp.com/v2/")
        super.init(baseURL: baseUrl, consumerKey: key, consumerSecret: secret);

        var token = BDBOAuthToken(token: accessToken, secret: accessSecret, expiration: nil)
        self.requestSerializer.saveAccessToken(token)
    }

    func searchWithTerm(term: String, success: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void, failure: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation! {
        // For additional parameters, see http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api
        var parameters = ["term": term, "ll": "37.77493,-122.419415"]
        return self.GET("search", parameters: parameters, success: success, failure: failure)
    }

    func searchWithTerm(term: String, deal: Bool, radius: Int, sort: Int, categories: String, success: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void, failure: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation! {
        // For additional parameters, see http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api
        var parameters = NSDictionary()
        if (radius == -1) {
            parameters = ["term": term, "ll": "37.77493,-122.419415", "deals_filter": deal, "sort": sort, "category_filter":categories]
        }
        else {
            var meter:Double = Double(radius) * 1609.34
            parameters = ["term": term, "ll": "37.77493,-122.419415", "deals_filter": deal, "radius_filter": meter, "sort": sort, "category_filter":categories]
        }
        return self.GET("search", parameters: parameters as [NSObject : AnyObject], success: success, failure: failure)
    }


}
```

I made a model class for the restaurants here:

```
import UIKit

class Resturant: NSObject {
    var name: String!
    var thumbUrl: String!
    var address: String!
    var jsonData: NSData!

    init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        thumbUrl = dictionary["thumbUrl"] as? String
        address = dictionary["address"] as? String
    }

    class func searchWithQuery(query: String, completion: ([Resturant]!, NSError!) -> Void) {
        YelpClient.sharedInstance.searchWithTerm(query, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            println(response)
        let JSONObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)
            }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        }
    }
}
```

`let JSONObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)`

This line of code prompts this error:

`Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x10b914a60) to 'NSData' (0x10b913a48).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ARE getting the response JSON. It's just that it is a binarized `NSData` object which you would want to convert to JSON object, if I am not wrong. Right now, I guess it will print illegible blocks of alpha numeric characters, right?

Well, you can do something like:

```
class func searchWithQuery(query: String, completion: ([Resturant]!, NSError!) -> Void) {
        YelpClient.sharedInstance.searchWithTerm(query, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            println(response) //Illegible block of data
            let JSONObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)
             println(JSONObject)//Prints JSON

            }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        }
    }
```

**EDIT #1**

Looks like it is the case of bad request. Be clear about the contract between the client and the server for this work. There must be some parameter that might be missing or something unexpected request. I'm afraid we cannot help you as we do not know what that contract is.

**EDIT #2**

At this point of code ...

```
let JSONObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)
```

... the API accepts the response type as `NSData`. But, your response type is `NSDictionary`. It would be giving you a warning; however there is no type checking at the compile time, it compiles. But the runtime is trying to treat `response` as `NSData`, but it is not; it is actually a `NSDictionary`, crashes.

Just log the `NSDictionary`. You'll get the results.

**Edit #3**
Your final code should like this:

```
class func searchWithQuery(query: String, completion: ([Resturant]!, NSError!) -> Void) {
            YelpClient.sharedInstance.searchWithTerm(query, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
                println(response) //Illegible block of data
                let responseInfo = response as! NSDictionary
                println(responseInfo)
                //Prints JSON

                }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            }
        }
```

Comment: IT actually doesn't print anything... which is odd.

Comment: Yes, see the edited answer. Kinda missed a line of code there. My bad.

Comment: As in nothing is printed, even if i try to serialize the json. Even before that nothing was printing, which seems to be my problem.

Comment: Oh, looks like there is something wrong with the response. Log the `error` in the failure block  and see if that prints.

Comment: Do you have an API document that you refer to?

Comment: I played around with the consumer key and it now generates JSON data. However it has this one thread kill, which is in the updated Question!!!

Comment: Good! Looks like all the parsing is done for you. Log the response, you'll be done.

Comment: Yes. The runtime is trying to treat the NSDictionary as NSData. Since your response is of type NSDictionary, you might as well log it and get the response. It will be in form of key value pairs.

Comment: Can you provide the code? I'm not exactly sure what you mean, my english is not good

Comment: response is of type anyObject.. It is not of type NSDictionary? I have to explicitly cast response as NSData or else it will not compile

Comment: You cast it to `NSDictionary` first. Like this: `let info = response as! NSDictionary`. See that it will cast successfully.

Comment: `let JSONObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response as! NSDictionary, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)` does not work.

Comment: Log the response. Not the JSON. Wait, I'll correct the answer.

Comment: I see... that makes so much more sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: How come casting the response as an NSDictionary prints it out in JSON format? Sorry, just curious

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84843/discussion-between-avismara-and-varun-varahabotla).